# SwiftUI TextField or UITextField with tag in MacOs

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I was trying replicate the behaviour that macOs Mail.app is doing, when you use the search bar to search for an email, it allows you to add a "tag" inside the field. The tag becomes a button you can remove, type around it, and click it.

[image]

Looking into the documentation or third party libraries yielded no result.

I had an idea about trying to achieve it similiar to a `ButtonStyle` to have a `TextFieldStyle` and looked promising at first, but got stuck there too with.

```
struct TaggedTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    // Parse body, and find tags
    ForEach(parts){
      if(parts.isTag){
        Text(parts.value)
      } else {
         TextField(
            "Part",
            text: $parts.value
        )
      }
    }
    .padding()
    .background(Color.yellow.cornerRadius(8))
  }
}
```

I haven't been able to to make it work with that way. Is there a way to achieve this in such manner?

Comment: `TextFieldStyle`is not a public protocol (yet), so you can't customize it. Maybe `.searchable`with suggestions can help you to some extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, had a bit of play with this, and found a way (thanks to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69158652/swiftui-multi-colours-text-in-textfield)

Basically, I have a `TextField` that has a `ViewModifier` attached to it. Looking like this:

```
TextField(
 "Placeholder",
 text: .constant("Text")
)
.modifier(TextFieldModifier(text: "TextOverlayWithExtra"))
```

And the modifier:

```
struct TextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    var text: String
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            // Clear color for the TextField
            .foregroundColor(.clear)
            // Overlay with text and extra
            .overlay(
                HStack(spacing: 0.0) {
                    // This Swift View splits the text and adds what I need
                    TextFieldHighlightedVariables(text)
                    Spacer()
                }
                    .padding(.top, 2)
                    .padding(.leading, 4)
                ,
                alignment: .topLeading
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @norwegiandev , can you please share what TextFieldHighlightedVariables does? I have a similar requirement